# Write data from database to a CSV file

Tags: java, csv, database

I have a database containing a high amount of data. I want my app to filter and select only some of it, and save it into a CSV file or JSON.

For the moment I have this method which takes the data from the database and puts it in a CSV:

```
void viewAllCounters (String tableName, long startDate, long endDate, Connection c) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "SELECT receivedtime, source, numulethbytesinter, numdlethbytesinter, numulethbytessent, numdlethbytessent, "
            + "numuniquegtpteids, numulbytessenttoaccl, numdlbytessenttoaccl "
            + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE CAST(receivedtime AS integer) BETWEEN "+ startDate +" AND " + endDate +" ORDER BY receivedtime;";

    try {
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        int i = 0;
        double last = 0;
        DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

        try {
            File file = new File("KPI-"+tableName+"-"+ endDate +".csv");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.append("Date");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("Source");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("AUIDR");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("ADIDR");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("AUEDR");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("ADEDR");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("AUTPG");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("ADTPG");
            fileWriter.append(',');
            fileWriter.append("AST");
            fileWriter.append('\n');


            while (rs.next()) {
                if (last != 0){
                    String receivedtime = rs.getString("receivedtime");
                    String source = rs.getString("source");

                    double numulethbytesinter = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numulethbytesinter"));
                    double numdlethbytesinter = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numdlethbytesinter"));
                    double numulethbytessent = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numulethbytessent"));
                    double numdlethbytessent = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numdlethbytessent"));

                    double numuniquegtptieds = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numuniquegtpteids"));
                    double numulbytessenttoaccl = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numulbytessenttoaccl"));
                    double numdlbytessenttoaccl = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numdlbytessenttoaccl"));

                    //period between this entry and the last one (in second)
                    if (Double.parseDouble(receivedtime) > last) {
                        double period = Double.parseDouble(receivedtime) - last;                 

                        double AUIDR = (8*numulethbytesinter)/(1000000*period);
                        double ADIDR = (8*numdlethbytesinter)/(1000000*period);
                        double AUEDR = (8*numulethbytessent)/(1000000*period);
                        double ADEDR = (8*numdlethbytessent)/(1000000*period);
                        double AUTPG, ADTPG;

                        if (numuniquegtptieds != 0){
                            AUTPG = (8*numulbytessenttoaccl)/(numuniquegtptieds*1000000*period);
                            ADTPG = (8*numdlbytessenttoaccl)/(numuniquegtptieds*1000000*period);
                        }else{
                            AUTPG = 0;
                            ADTPG = 0;
                        }

                        double AST = (8*(numdlbytessenttoaccl+numulbytessenttoaccl))/(1000000*period);

                        String dateReceived = formatter.format(new Date (Long.parseLong(receivedtime)*1000));

                        fileWriter.append(dateReceived);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append(source);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append("" + AUIDR);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append("" + ADIDR);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append("" +AUEDR);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append("" + ADEDR);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append("" + AUTPG);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append("" +ADTPG);
                        fileWriter.append(',');
                        fileWriter.append("" + AST);
                        fileWriter.append('\n');

                    i++;
                    }
                } else {
                    last = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("receivedtime"));
                }
            }
        fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage() + "\n\n\n");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
         System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage() + "\n\n\n");    } 
    finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

This method is in a class called `Dbfunctions` which is called in the main method of my main class. I could add more fields to get in the future.

As you can see I create a CSV file and add all the data. But I am wondering, is there any way to make it faster or at least more readable?

I thought to add all this data in a `List` and return this list to create this. I guess the best for me is a `Queue`? Fast to insert fast to remove and first in first out. I could create a `Queue<Queue<String>>` so I will have:

```
Queue(QueueIterration1{[String DateIterration1],[String SourceIterration1]...}, QueueIterration2{...}, ...).
```

So I will pop the `QueueIterration1` then a `for` loop to pop each element. Then pop `QueueIterration2` etc...

So my question is: is it a good idea? Speaking about performances, time to write all the data. And do you have any suggestions on how to improve my code?

(Now I have 4 methods like this one to take different data from the database.)

Answer (score 3):

### On the `append`

The `append` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#append(char)) returns the writer, so one improvement could be to leverage this and chain the calls together.

So, where you're currently doing this:

```
fileWriter.append("Date");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("Source");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("AUIDR");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("ADIDR");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("AUEDR");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("ADEDR");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("AUTPG");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("ADTPG");
fileWriter.append(',');
fileWriter.append("AST");
fileWriter.append('\n');
```

You can instead write it as:

```
fileWriter
  .append("Date")
  .append(',')
  .append("Source")
  .append(',')
  .append("AUIDR")
  .append(',')
  .append("ADIDR")
  .append(',')
  .append("AUEDR")
  .append(',')
  .append("ADEDR")
  .append(',')
  .append("AUTPG")
  .append(',')
  .append("ADTPG")
  .append(',')
  .append("AST")
.append('\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the concerns I have about your current code:

- You are building your SQL query by appending directly Strings

  ```
  String query = "SELECT receivedtime, source, numulethbytesinter, numdlethbytesinter, numulethbytessent, numdlethbytessent, "
      + "numuniquegtpteids, numulbytessenttoaccl, numdlbytessenttoaccl "
      + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE CAST(receivedtime AS integer) BETWEEN "+ startDate +" AND " + endDate +" ORDER BY receivedtime;";
  ```

  This is not a good idea as it can lead to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). What you want to use instead is a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), [that tackles with this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1582161/1743880). A `PreparedStatement` is created by calling [`prepareStatement(sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-) on the connection. All the parameters are replaced with the `?` placeholder.

  ```
  String query = "SELECT receivedtime, source, numulethbytesinter, numdlethbytesinter, numulethbytessent, numdlethbytessent, "
      + "numuniquegtpteids, numulbytessenttoaccl, numdlbytessenttoaccl "
      + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE CAST(receivedtime AS integer) BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY receivedtime;";

  PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(query);
  stmt.setLong(1, startDate);
  stmt.setLong(2, endDate);
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
  ```

  You can't use a placeholder [for the FROM part](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18364463/1743880), unfortunately.
- You could get rid of the `finally` clause by using a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- Consider making your SQL query a constant. What I mean by that is that you could make the SQL query a constant by declaring it `private static final String`.
- You are using the pattern `Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(...))` when you could simply use [`rs.getDouble(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble-java.lang.String-). This would simplify the code. Also, you are parsing `receivedtime` multiple times in your code (I counted 4). Consider parsing it only once and reusing it.

There is one suggestion that I could make:

- Consider writing more specialized methods. You could refactor the code writing to a file into a specific method. Or, you could even make a generic class `CsvWriter` that would handle writing the CSV file when you are adding elements to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
I change the query to a prepare statement, but I will use it only in this method so I won't make it constant 
I didn't thought about  `rs.getDouble(...)` of course I changed it. The `receivetime` is used three time as double and once as long that's why I had let it as string. So I changed to a double and declare it before the `if` statement so I can use  it in the else.
I made two try-with-resources`try (PreparedStatement stmt = .. )` and `try (FileWriter fileWriter = ...)`.
For the CsvWriter method I agree, see the end of my question. I don't really know what should be the best.

Answer (score 1):

### Not closing `fileWriter` if there is an error

> ```
> File file = new File("KPI-"+tableName+"-"+ endDate +".csv");
> FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
> ...
> fileWriter.flush();
> fileWriter.close();
> ```

You should always close your resources in a finally block or with a try-with-resources. This prevent bugging code when you don't have any file channels left.

```
File file = new File("KPI-"+tableName+"-"+ endDate +".csv");
try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)){
    ...
    fileWriter.flush();
}
```

### Confusing variable names

> ```
>                 double numulethbytesinter = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numulethbytesinter"));
>                 double numdlethbytesinter = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numdlethbytesinter"));
>                 double numulethbytessent = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numulethbytessent"));
>                 double numdlethbytessent = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numdlethbytessent"));
>                 double numuniquegtptieds = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numuniquegtpteids"));
>                 double numulbytessenttoaccl = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numulbytessenttoaccl"));
>                 double numdlbytessenttoaccl = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("numdlbytessenttoaccl"));
> ```

All these variables have confusing simulair names, this makes it hard to follow them.